# Storage Audio in Sqlite in newfolder

Tags: android, sqlite, audio

I use thus code and it works fine with me

```
String fileName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() +"/Music/Diary.flac";
```

Music folder is already exist is SD card , I want to  make folder New Folder created automatically in SD card , I tried something like that

```
String fileName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() +"/NewFolder/Diary.flac";
```

but it's not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a directory first. Try this:

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/NewFolder", "/Diary.flac");
    file.getParentFile().mkdir();
    if(!file.exists()){
        try {
                  file.createNewFile();
              } catch (IOException e) {
                  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                  e.printStackTrace();
              }
    }
```